# Remove trailing middle initials with regular expressions

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a list of people, and some people have a first name with a middle initial, and some just have a first name. I want to create a regular expression whose first group matches just the first name.

Some examples:

- "Ben t" -> "Ben"
- "Lisa Ann t" -> "Lisa Ann"
- "Ben" -> "Ben"

If I just wanted to remove the trailing middle initial this would be easy with something like `(.*)( .)`, but I can't be sure the middle initial will always exist. I am doing this in Postgres, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Lisa Ann t', '\\s\\S+$', '');
```

Comment: This returns `'Lisa Ann t'`. But changing it to `( .) $` Might work

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do using a `case` and string operations:

```
select (case when firstname like '% _' then left(firstname, length(firstname) - 2)
             else firstname
         end) as firstname
```